# Where to locate user data in Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application where a user's profile image is stored. I originally stored the images in the static directory like so:

```
application.py
templates/
static/userdata/user/icon.png
```

Though I don't think this is a good idea because it is not good practice to modify the static directory in production.

I tried making a new userdata folder at root like so:

```
application.py
templates/
static/
userdata/user/icon.png
```

Though when I try to access the file with Jinja and HTML,

```
<img src="/userdata/user/icon.png">
```

the image does not show. Why is this?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Flask doesn't route arbitrary URLs, only those it knows about. `static` is a built-in endpoint. If you want `/userdata/` to work, you'll need to handle that yourself. Since this is for a production site, your best option is to configure your http server (e.g., Nginx, Apache) to serve files from the `userdata` folder directly.

Comment: @dirn How do Flask applications usually handle user's data?

Comment: If by a user's data you mean images, you're best bet is to allow your http server to serve the files for you, similar to how you want to handle your static assets. If you want them served by the development server, though, you'll need to define an endpoint that behaves similar to `static`.

Comment: How would I go about this? I'm guessing this is something I must set up with my hosting server?

Answer (score -1):

Use the url_for function

.html

```
<img src="{{ url_for('userdata', filename='/user/icon.png')}}">
```

.py

```
from flask import send_file
@route('/userdata/<filename:filename>')
def get_user_data_files(filename):
    return send_file(app.config['USER_DATA_FOLDER'] + filename)
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I found it isn't best practice to store user data in the static folder because the data changes. I would like to access to files outside the static folder like said in the question.

Comment: This would only work if you defined an endpoint called `userdata`.